# Optimizing Entity Framework Query - Timout Expired

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, query-optimization

I have 2 very simple queries in entity framework that group by a column which is a foreign key. In other words the table fields are:

```
pk : Primary key
name : name of object
f1: foreign key1
f2: foreign key2
...
```

I am getting timeout exceptions, in particular this one:

```
Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
```

The queries are:

```
var q = from x in db.Table select x;
var query_1 = q.GroupBy (record => record.f1);
var query2 = q.GroupBy(record => new {record.f1, record.f2});
```

I have about 30,000 records in DB and I cannot understand why a simple group by will timeout. Do you have any suggestions of what should I do? Since I am using Entity Framework 4.1, I want to abstract the databse from implementation so I would like a solution that doesn'e change anything in the db engine itself. 
Can indexing the f1 or f2 (or both) fields get me a faster query? If so, can someone please explain the concept of indexing as well as how to do is in Enfity Framework?
I don't think increasing the timeout should be the only solution I should settle on, I am afraid the issue will remain with more data coming.

***EDIT***:
I have tried what is mentioned [here](http://coding.abel.nu/2012/02/adding-indexes-with-ef-migrations/) about EF Migrations.

I have this class as result:

```
namespace DataAccessLayer.Migrations
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;

    public partial class IX_Table1_fId : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Creating Index");
            CreateIndex("Table1", "fId");
            Console.WriteLine("Index Created");
        }

        public override void Down()
        {
            DropIndex("Table1", "IX_Table1_fId");
        }
    }
}
```

However, when does this code get called? I do not see the print statements I have there in the console.

Comment: The `Up` and `Down` methods are called automatically at application startup (if you have the default DB initializer), or when you explicitly type `update-database` in the package manager console. In the latter case, the console output disappears into a black hole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you have to do is to check where the performance problem is. Start a SQL Server profiler instance, then run the code doing the query. Capture the actual SQL query run and check how long it takes.

If it is the SQL execution that takes time, the easiest way to analyze it is to paste it into SQL Server Management Studio and run it from there and check the query plan. It will suggest what indexes to add.

If the query itself is fast, then EFs processing of the result is the problem (which I doubt in this case).

How you apply the indexes on the database depends on how you handle your database schema. If you hare using EF Migrations to update the schema from the code, then you can add indexes as either a [separate migration step](http://coding.abel.nu/2012/02/adding-indexes-with-ef-migrations/) or [together with the table creation](http://coding.abel.nu/2012/02/indexes-in-code-based-ef-migrations/).

Comment: Is there a simple way just to make the f1 and f2 columns indexes in the model? I am using Code-First approach by the way.

Comment: You have to make it in a migration step. There is no support for creating indexes by including attributes in the model classes.

Comment: The index was added but the timeout problem still exists. Do you know how I can increase the timeout programatically

Comment: I'd suggest that you take a closer look at the execution plan to see if any more indexes are needed instead. Hitting the timeout is a hint of something being really wrong. Otherwise, you'd better ask a new question. With this being "closed" with an accepted answer it will have very low views.